# How can I get the opposite value of a Bool in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, boolean

My specific case is I am trying to toggle the nav bar hidden and showing.

```
    let navHidden = !self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navHidden!, animated: true)
```

Is not working for me like it normally would in Obj-C.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The exclamation point is on the wrong side of the boolean. The way you've written it would indicate that the boolean could be nil. You want !navHidden.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasn't trying to invert it twice.  It won't compile unless I have the ! on the right.  This is what is working for me:

        let navHidden = self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(!navHidden!, animated: true)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Removed that part of my comment.

Answer (score 4):

`navHidden!` is to make sure this is not optional. `!navHidden` is the correct way to do that.

From Apple's [book](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_483).

> Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.

Answer (score 1):

navHidden is an optional. And you explictely unwrap that optional (which means you get a crash if navHidden is nil). Clearly something is wrong here. I suggest

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
    let navHidden = navController.navigationBarHidden
    navController.setNavigationBarHidden (!navHidden, animated:true)
}
```